# jsIt gives a bracketing error, but it doesn't appear. Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

i am new to javasacript. Besides, I am developing an application with React. I am getting a parsing error today. probably a punctuation error. but I couldn't find where. can you help me ?

```
export const CategorySuite = ({items}) => {
  
  return (
{items.map(item => <Item item={item}/>)}
    
  );
};
```

Error =>

```
  13 |   
  14 |   return (
> 15 | {items.map(item => <Item item={item}/>)}
     |       ^
  16 |     
  17 |   );
  18 | };
```

Comment: What's with the outer set of { ... }, what are those supposed to achieve? Looks to me like this would simply mean object syntax in this place - but an object would require a property name, not just a value.

Comment: when i click on the menu i want it to show data from CategorySuite. I have products in Item.js (design) and App.js (function)

Comment: The syntax error is the `{ }`. It means you want to return an object - but then you have to specify keys and values, e.g. `{ type: 'apple', color: 'red' }` - but you are just specifying one expression (like `{ 'apple' }`) which isn't making sense. (There is also the syntax `{ type }` etc. but that's an _identifier_ and not an expression, and it equals to `{ type: type }`.) I guess you want to just drop the `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not returning JSX, you can't use the outer parentheses. Should be just:

```
return items.map(...)
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') now it gives error like this.. When I write like this, it works, but I need an error.
````export const CategorySuite= ()=>{
  return (
    <div className="category">

    </div>
  )
}

Comment: @psyduckduck that's because items is (apparently) not an array, but that's a separate issue.